# How to Make XMLHttpRequest in Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

How can I make an XMLHttpRequest without any restrictions to Content Security Policy? Just want to get a proof of concept running and can handle permissions better later. I keep getting two the the following errors when trying to make a get request to https:///v1/api?q=value

First:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://<domain>/v1/api?q=value' 
  because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
    "connect-src http://localhost:3000 https://localhost:3000".
```

Second:

```
Error in response to tabs.query: SecurityError: 
  Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 
    Refused to connect to 'https://<domain>/v1/api?q=value' 
     because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
Error: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 
  Refused to connect to 'https://<domain>/v1/api?q=value' 
    because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
```

I did add the following to my manifest file:

```
"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self' https://<domain>"
```

Can anyone help me configure my extension so that I can make requests without any restrictions? I'm using https://github.com/jhen0409/react-chrome-extension-boilerplate as a base. Thanks!

Comment: Just making sure you've seen this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing

Comment: You need to make the request in the background/event page. There are some/many examples on stackoverflow.

Comment: Also, use fetch instead of xhr. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch